# are dynamic columns possible with MVC.Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building an interface for lookup table management into an MVC5 application. Each lookup is encapsulated in its own Model. The hope/idea was that I could dynamically feed whichever Model I choose into a single Razor page containing an [MVC.Grid](https://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/). Unfortunately, the syntax for MVC.Grid demands that I hard-code the properties of the given model.

Is there any way to dynamically add a column, for each property of the given Model?

```
@model IQueryable<Person>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
        columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");
        columns.Add(model => model.MaritalStatus).Titled("Marital status");
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply show your grid in your view with all column, you just have to use in your view `GetHTML` of your declared `WebGrid`:

```
@model IQueryable <Person>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<div>@grid.GetHtml()</div>
```

**Edit:** *with some more option*

```
@model IQueryable <Person>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: true);
}

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle : "table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered", 
htmlAttributes: new
    {
        id = "grid1"
    })
</div>
```

As you can see you can customize your grid behaviour in your c# code to sort, to limit rows number...etc.
And also do style to your HTML with applying some style to grid, give an Id,...etc.

You can check this two link, to know more, because there is a lot of option that can't show in a single post.

[Microsoft WebGrid.GetHtml Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webgrid.gethtml?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)

[MVC Webgrid basics – Simple grid with paging and sorting and selection](https://bobnoordam.nl/aspnet-mvc/mvc-webgrid-basics-simple-grid-with-paging-and-sorting-and-selection/)

Comment: I appreciate that your answer demonstrates a way to display grids without hard-coding each column. However, your example provides no control over the header text.  More importantly, I chose to work with MVC.Grid due to its bevy of built-in features: filtering (by column), search (of the whole grid), export (to Excel), etc. Losing all that functionality just to dynamically display a model creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: I just wanted to make it as simple as possible that you understand well how to implement it, let me edit for you for some detail ;)

Comment: Um...in "simplifying" this, you're kind of missing the point. This really was not a question about preferred choices of grids. It's about dynamically looping through properties. Even if I went with WebGrid *and* gave up the export support *and* spent hours programming in the the type-specific filters that aren't readily available...headers. I won't get formatted headers without specifying each column (like I already do in MVC.Grid), and thus I would still be looking for a way to *dynamically loop through properties.*

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples on [MVC.Grid](https://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/Datatable) page is done using data tables, if possible you can use that.

Other than that it boils down to creating an expression which access the data somehow. You can use your own data structure with column names as keys, you can create dynamic expressions using .NET expression builder, etc.

```
@(Html
    .Grid(Model.Rows)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        foreach (var column in Model.DynamicColumns)
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.GetValueFor(column.Name)).Titled(column.Label);
        }
        // or
        foreach (var column in Model.DynamicColumns)
        {
            columns.Add(column.BuildDataAccessExpression()).Titled(column.Label);
        }
    })
)
```

If `.Add(...)` method doesn't support your expression, you can use less restricting function api instead with `.Add().RenderedAs(...)`.

Comment: I appreciate that your answer demonstrates a way to dynamically add columns. However, it sidesteps my desire to do this [for each property of a given Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65524000/4186251). `column.Label` doesn't retrieve the Display Name from a Model. `.BuildDataAccessExpression()` also does not appear to be legitimate code. Confirmation of the concept is nice, but I was hoping for more than just pseudocode to build from. [My update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865983/4186251) is a closer step in the right direction...except the MVC.Grid breaks along the way.

Comment: ...having said all this: my output does not naturally lend itself to the C# `DataTable` class...but _most_ of the settings that vary column to column in [your example](https://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/Datatable) are strings. Investigating. Each column is hard-coded to the `String` type, though. Can type be set with a variable string? (If not: again, my attempts to be dynamic are thwarted by the need to hard-code.)

Comment: I just shown a concept. I didn't knew you want to explicitly build your columns through `GetType().GetProperties()` API. Filter and sorting have to be enabled on a column level, because grid automatically disables it for complex expressions like that as they only work on in memory data.


You would still have to build expressions if you want sorting and filtering to work with database provider.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something more in the direction of what I was expecting.

For a given model...

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Marital Status")]
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Years Married")]
    public int Years { get; set; }
}
```

I can *almost* dynamically add a column for each property of the model like this:

```
@model IQueryable<Person>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        foreach (var column in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
        {
            var type = typeof(Person);
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(column.Name);
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);
            var displayname = ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;

            columns.Add(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(column.Name).GetValue(m)).Titled(displayname);
        }
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
)
```

However...filter and sort have disappeared, now that I'm no longer hard-coding the columns. Adding event listeners via JavaScript also now fails. The dynamic parsing of model properties has broken SOMEthing...strong typing, maybe?

Any further insight in this direction, anybody?